# NGRX - How to subscribe to multiple requests that update a list, but prevent it from loading multiple times on the first load?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data

I'm working with Angular-NGRX and i have 3 components that can modify the data of a list. In the main component I listen for all the changes to update the listing and it works. The problem is that the first load subscribes me 3 times.

This is the ngOnInit of the main component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Change order
    this.store.select(state => state.shared.orderBy).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      tap(resp => {
        this.orderBy = resp;
        this._cmsFunctions.deselectAll('Resource');
      }),
      switchMap(resp => this._dynamicComponentsService.loadResources(this.itemsToShow, this.tabCounter, this.orderBy, this.filters, this.searchTerm, this.company, this.workgroup, (this.paramCode) ? this.paramCode : 0))
      ).subscribe();

    // Change filters
    this.store.select(state => state.shared.filters).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      tap(resp => {
        this.filters = resp;
        this._cmsFunctions.deselectAll('Resource');
      }),
      switchMap(resp => this._dynamicComponentsService.loadResources(this.itemsToShow, this.tabCounter, this.orderBy, this.filters, this.searchTerm, this.company, this.workgroup, (this.paramCode) ? this.paramCode : 0))
      ).subscribe();

    // Change search term
    this.store.select(state => state.shared.searchTerm).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      tap(resp => {
        this.searchTerm = resp;
        this._cmsFunctions.deselectAll('Resource');
      }),
      switchMap(resp => this._dynamicComponentsService.loadResources(this.itemsToShow, this.tabCounter, this.orderBy, this.filters, this.searchTerm, this.company, this.workgroup, (this.paramCode) ? this.paramCode : 0))
      ).subscribe();
  }
```

And all i need is that when starting it only subscribes once:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUt8x.png)

How can I improve this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be making calls to a data service from the component, and certainly not based on selector calls. You should be dispatching an Action which is captured and handled by an Effect. You can use `dataLoading` and `dataLoaded` flags in your store, for example, to prevent multiple loads.